# How to create a large number of documents with embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I was looking at the example here:

```
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader"
}
// address documents
{
   patron_id: "joe", // reference to patron document
   street: "123 Fake Street",
   city: "Faketon",
   state: "MA",
   zip: "12345"
}
{
   patron_id: "joe",
   street: "1 Some Other Street",
   city: "Boston",
   state: "MA",
   zip: "12345"
}
```

Where they embed the address document inside the person document. The example makes sense if you have a single item in your person document, but how would you scale this if you had a person document with 100 items and addresses for each of them? Is there a way to create a schema and upload the data or do you have to manually embed the address documents for each person?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the Data Model Design section in their documentation. For this pattern the [Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) would match.

In short your User document would have an array containing the IDs of the referenced Address documents. But the Addresses are stored in a different collection. You would need a second query to select them.

Example from the documentation:

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   books: [123456789, 234567890, ...]
}
{
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
}
{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English"
}
```